# Wi-Fi doesn't work with NVIDIA drivers but OS takes forever to load on Nouveau

Tags: wireless, nvidia, touchpad

I have an Asus Q536fd that I've been using with Ubuntu for a while. I've been on multiple versions and all have the following issue. I'm currently using Ubuntu 20.04 but have used 18.10, 19.04, 19.10. So here are the issues:

**Using the Nouveau driver:**

- After typing in the password, the OS takes a good minute or two to leave the purple screen and actual boot the GUI.
- Also, the touchpad doesn't work for about 30 seconds after waking up from suspend, but the touchscreen still does and so does an external mouse.

**Using the NVIDIA 440 driver (or any others):**

- the above issues go away but my Wi-Fi connection doesn't seem to work.  I'll load up a page in Chrome and it just keeps spinning. The connection is there, but it doesn't ever load a page. The same thing happens in Firefox.
- Also the Software & Updates program no longer works (presumably because the Wi-Fi isn't working).

Any help/guidance here would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Additional logs:

```
 -- Logs begin at Tue 2020-03-10 19:27:14 EDT, end at Thu 2020-05-07 11:56:47 EDT. --
May 07 11:56:47 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD gnome-shell[2830]: [2982:1:0507/115647.034213:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a >
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD wpa_supplicant[1163]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-49 noise=9999 txrate=866700
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD wpa_supplicant[1163]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=WORLD
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0x07fd0003]
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD6866C95 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0DFB61E5 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3A835B90 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x79C3E19C | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x234389B9 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80577A99 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0064019C | last host cmd
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC088627C | stack pointer
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x007BBF39 | frame pointer
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6BF1DF06 | umac minor
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | umac major
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC00843E8 | umac data2
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000800 | umac data1
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC00843E8 | umac interruptlink2
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC00843E8 | umac interruptlink1
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC008885E | umac branchlink2
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000070 | NMI_INTERRUPT_LMAC_FATAL
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 7
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000C0B8 | flow_handler
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08081425 | timestamp
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | l2p_addr_match
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00002020 | l2p_duration
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001ACAA | wait_event
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0064019C | last cmd Id
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x404134CC | isr3
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08001802 | isr2
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80022006 | isr0
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0BD4001C | hcmd
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C89008 | board version
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000312 | hw version
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6BF1DF06 | uCode version minor
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | uCode version major
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x007BBF1A | time gp2
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000010 | tsf hi
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA49DF701 | tsf low
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1380C8DC | beacon time
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | data3
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | data2
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00002FC8 | data1
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0047932A | interruptlink1
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004882DA | branchlink2
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00802EF4 | trm_hw_status0
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00004435 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 46.6bf1df06.0
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
May 07 11:56:46 ronnie-ZenBook-Q536FD-Q536FD kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
```

Comment: 20.04 has been struggling with NVIDIA. First release notes mentioned that. I was having a problem on my ASUS that was cleared up by the most recent driver update. What version are you using now?

Comment: Hey.  Yeah, this issue has persisted since 18.10.  I tried nvidia-440 most recently but the issue was also occurring with the past few nvidia drivers I've tried too.

Comment: What's your wifi driver? Maybe a conflict with NVIDIA in some bizarre way. Have you looked through your journal for errors?

Comment: I just looked at them.  I attached them above.  Pretty much all of that was red in the journal before posting them here.  I do not get those errors when using nouveau driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end I kept installing uninstalling nvidia drivers.  Eventually my device no longer "saw" the nvidia gpu which has in fact been a blessing.  I think my device was fighting between the integrated graphics chip and the nvidia gpu and causing all of these problems (even with nouveau).  Now without the nvidia chip being recognized, I no longer have any issues logging in. My touchpad has no issues and my wifi works great!

So the answer is: If you don't need the nvidia gpu, then completely uninstall it from your drivers.